# Simple Injector Ioc DBContext with EasynetQ message life cycle

Tags: c#, entity-framework, inversion-of-control, simple-injector, easynetq

I have an issue with the EF's `DBContext`'s life cycle using Simple Injector , I have a worker service that is running continuously but I want the `DBContext` to be initialized during the messages' lifespan and not for the life time of the worker service application.

There are examples on how to do this with Autofac but I am having trouble coming up with something with Simple Injector. Has anyone done this previously?

See: http://nblumhardt.com/2011/01/an-autofac-lifetime-primer/

The current implementation for our registration is:

```
var registration = applicationLifestyle.CreateRegistration<ProjectContext>(container);
container.AddRegistration(typeof(IProjectContext), registration);
container.AddRegistration(typeof(ProjectContext), registration);
```

And inside the worker module we have:

```
container.RegisterModuleScoped(new CodeModule(), Lifestyle.Transient);
```

However we do not want to be using Lifestyle Transient for our `DBContext`, we want this to be alive during the message handler.

**Update:**

Steven, that sounds like great solution, just having some issue registering the `IMessageHandler<T>` e.g.

The constructor of type `LifetimeScopeMessageHandlerDecorator` contains the parameter of type `Func<NoticeMessageHandler>` with name 'decorateeFactory' that is not registered.

I have tried to register this before and tried to leave it out and many variations but no luck. Here is how I registered the decorator:

```
container.RegisterSingleDecorator(
    typeof(NoticeMessageHandler),
    typeof(LifetimeScopeMessageHandlerDecorator));
```

ERROR:

> The constructor of type LifetimeScopeMessageHandlerDecorator contains the parameter of type `Func<NoticeMessageHandler>` with name 'decorateeFactory' that is not registered.

Comment: Use lifetime scopes, see [here](http://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/lifetimes.html#scoped), and start the scope at the start of the messages' lifespan.

Comment: And read the [decorator documentation]( http://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/advanced.html#decorators) as well. The exception you get indicates that this class is not a decorator. If you keep having trouble, please post the code for your decorator as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you should do is wrapping the execution of the message with a scope. You can use the `LifetimeScopeLifestyle` for instance. Where to wrap this is of course completely dependent on your architecture, but I imagine you having a message handler, and in that case you can define a decorator for this:

```
public class LifetimeScopeMessageHandlerDecorator<T>
    : IMessageHandler<T>
{
    private readonly Func<IMessageHandler<T>> decorateeFactory;
    public LifetimeScopeMessageHandlerDecorator(Container container,
        Func<IMessageHandler<T>> decorateeFactory) {
        this.decorateeFactory = decorateeFactory;
    }

    public void Handle(T message) {
        using (this.container.BeginLifetimeScope()) {
            var decoratee = this.decorateeFactory.Invoke();
            decoratee.Handle(message);
        }
    }
}
```

This means that you will have to register your DbContext with the `LifetimeScopeLifestyle` and register your decorator. Perhaps your architecture looks differently, but the idea will always be the same: wrap the lifetime scope around the resolving and execution of the message handler.

Comment: Okay that sounds like great solution, just having some issue registering the IMessageHandler<T> e.g.

 The constructor of type LifetimeScopeMessageHandlerDecorator contains the parameter of type Func<NoticeMessageHandler> with name 'decorateeFactory' that is not registered.

I have tried to register this before and tried to leave it out and many variations but no luck. Here is how I registered the decorator:

            container.RegisterSingleDecorator(
                typeof(NoticeMessageHandler),
                typeof(LifetimeScopeMessageHandlerDecorator));

Comment: @MichaelCarr take a close look at the decorator in my answer: the parameter contains a T.